Steam games won't show in apps menu
So I initially installed Steam using App Center, but that was launching really slow and I read that it's because I installed it from there. So I decided to uninstall it so I could reinstall using sudo apt. To uninstall it I used sudo snap remove --purge steam as I thought that would make sure all traces of it are removed.
Now that I have installed using sudo apt install steam (and running through the installer process), I find that some games aren't showing up in the apps menu when I install them (I can still run them from my Steam library). It seems like all the games I had installed with the snap version of Steam now don't show up, so I'm guessing there are some files left over that are messing with the currently installed version of Steam.
Any help would be great, thank you.

You purged Steam so any info in the Stem install is gone. Therefore I would expect the games icon to be gone. Your question is not clear on if you have reinstalled the games after purging and reinstalling Steam.

@David as I said in the question, I have now reinstalled steam using sudo apt and have installed some games with this version of steam. The ones that I had previously installed with the snap version now are not showing up in apps menu. I am still able to run them through my steam library. Sorry that this wasn't clear

Try Installing Steam as .deb from steam website I guess the problem is installing it from apt or snap.
Hope this helps
